# How can I filter out non-Japanese characters from my array?

Tags: javascript, json, addeventlistener

I currently have this http://jsfiddle.net/cuLa9mtf/8/

```
function wordStat(text) {
    return text.split('').filter(function(letter){
        return letter > '\u3040' && letter < '\u4DBF';
    }).reduce(function (stat, word) {
        if (!stat[word]) stat[word] = 0;
        stat[word]++;
        return stat;
    }, {});
}

var input = document.querySelector('#input');
var output = document.querySelector('#output');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    output.value = JSON.stringify(wordStat(input.value), 2, 2);
})
```

but it does not seem to work depending on where I copy the Japanese text from. If I copy and paste characters from [Rikai](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml) it works, and I see the results in the resulting array (intended result), but if I copy from a different site such as [Jisho dictionary](http://beta.jisho.org/search/%E9%83%BD%E9%81%93%E5%BA%9C%E7%9C%8C) it does not work (the characters get filtered out).

The way I am going to use this is: I will have a textbox where the user will paste their Japanese text and I will filter out anything that is not a Japanese character (take out [a-zA-Z all punctuation letters of other languages]. Which brings me to my question of how can I reliably filter out non-Japanese characters with front-end Javascript?

(According to [Rikai](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml) Japanese characters are unicode \u3040 - \u4DBF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at both your code and your Rikai link, it seems you have missed a large range of characters:  CJK unifed ideographs - Common and uncommon kanji ( 4e00 - 9faf)

I made a very small modification to your `filter` and it seems to be able to pick up the kanji characters from Jisho dictionary successfully:

```
function wordStat(text) {
    return text.split('').filter(function(letter){
        return (letter > '\u3040' && letter < '\u4DBF') || (letter > '\u4e00' && letter < '\u9faf');
    }).reduce(function (stat, word) {
        if (!stat[word]) stat[word] = 0;
        stat[word]++;
        return stat;
    }, {});
}

var input = document.querySelector('#input');
var output = document.querySelector('#output');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    output.value = JSON.stringify(wordStat(input.value), 2, 2);
});
```

Comment: This is what I get for staying up late and going straight to the bottom of the hex list assuming the hex values sequentially went straight up until the end. Thank you.